# Motor voltage and VFDs

Tags: power-supply, ac, vfd, parameters

Is it possible to use a motor with a lower voltage rating than the line input to the VFD that it's running on?

Most VFDs have a parameter to set the maximum motor voltage, what effect does this have?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure so I'll just comment that the VFD will simulate the lower voltage by limiting the width of the pulses being sent to the drive. The peak amplitude of the PWM signal will be the voltage on the VFD's internal DC link and this is \$ \sqrt 2 V_{RMS}\$. That means that the low voltage motor's winding insulation will need to be rated for the higher voltage of the VFD. It might not be!

[image]

There's a [good VFD tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v51yWKrEZJM&ab_channel=KEBAmerica%2CInc.) by KEB on YouTube. It may clarify some of the theory of operation for you.

Answer (score 0):

VFD’s control minimum starting f and V to overcome stiction and minimize starting current surge.

The V/f ratio is a user constant that leads to the maximum no load voltage and RPM.

Thus I assume the software has the features to limit these variables to your chosen target for Vmax and f max with a chosen V/f which is related to V/RPM by number of pole pairs

Answer (score 0):

Most VFDs have configuration inputs that allow the user to enter the motor nameplate rating information. That would include rated frequency and voltage. That make is possible to operate a motor that has a rated voltage that is considerably less than the VFD input or maximum output voltage. There are several data entry items, adjustments and selections involved. The manual for each specific VFD model should provide the details.

That offers the advantage of using a motor that might not be useable with direct connection to the power source. The disadvantage is that the cost of the VFD will be higher than a VFD with a voltage rating that is equal to the motor rating. That is not the best efficiency operation for the VFD, but that is only a slight disadvantage. There may also be some slight disadvantage in VFD performance.

With a VFD that has a higher voltage rating than the motor is that the motor can be operated at its rated torque above its rated voltage, frequency, speed and power. Overspeed operation is generally acceptable up to some limit, but the limit may be difficult to determine.